# Reduce the font size of the header

Tags: header-footer

My question is how to reduce the font size of the header, for example, a chapter is titled "The elementary proof of the theorem of primes" but it sticks with the numbering headlined, any solution?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}   
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,cancel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=red,
citecolor=styrmitcrnred, urlcolor=styrmitcrnblue]{hyperref}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]           
\newtheorem{ejemplo}{{\it Ejemplo}}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lema}[chapter]   
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}[chapter]  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\begin{document}
{
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin {center}



\medskip
\textbf{UNIVERSIDAD DE PANAMÁ}

\smallskip

\textbf{Facultad de Ciencias Naturales, Exactas y Tecnología}

\smallskip

\vspace{0.2cm}
\textbf{Departamento de Matemática}

\textbf{ Licenciatura en Matemática}


\vspace{2.5cm}

\textbf{\Large El Teorema de los Números Primos}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\textbf{Trabajo de Grado presentado por}

\textbf{Julio Trujillo\\ }

\vspace{0.3cm}

\textbf{Como requisito final para obtener\\ el título de Licenciado en Matemática}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\textbf{Área de Conocimiento: Teoría de Números}
\end {center}


\vspace{1.5cm}

\noindent \textbf{Director: Dr. } 


\vspace{3cm}

\rightline{ Fecha de Presentación}
}
.
.
.
\chapter{Prueba Elemental del Teorema de los Números Primos} %this is the problem
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete but minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem. We really can't help effectively without code because we know nothing about what's causing the problem.

Comment: The suggestion here would be to use `\chapter[<short title>]{<long title>}`, which will also add `<short title>` to the ToC.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether I hvae understood your question compeltely, but as I gather you want to reduce the title font size?

I would suggest using the `titlesec` package.
You would then have to add in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{book}
....
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter\quad}{0em}{}
% Or any smaller font size or font you need, instead of \bfseries\Large
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chapter{}}
...
\begin{document}
\chapter{Prueba Elemental del Teorema de los Números Primos}
...
\end{document}
```

I have not tested this exact code (possibly some typo), but it should do the job.

I hope this i helpful.